# I m getting a 405 'method not allowed' message after payment is accepted by stripe, it doesn't update my prisma database with a response

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, prisma, vercel, next.js13

I have an AI saas app which sends data to replicate.com and receives a response this goes well, but I want people to pay for this so I have a stripe account connected and I have made an endpoint /pages/api/strpe-webhook but the response from stripe is denied by my vercel server and it throws a 405 error.

As you see in the code I have a credit payment system where people can purchase after the purchase, my prisma schema should update the database, but nothing happens, I just keep on getting the 405 error. Underneath the code I also show you my prisma schema with the purchase model.

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import prisma from "../../lib/prismadb";
import Stripe from "stripe";
import { buffer } from "micro";
import Cors from "micro-cors";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!, {
  apiVersion: "2022-11-15",
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const webhookSecret: string = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET || "";

const cors = Cors({
  allowMethods: ["POST", "HEAD"],
});

const webhookHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const buf = await buffer(req);
    const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"]!;

    let event: Stripe.Event;

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        buf.toString(),
        sig,
        webhookSecret
      );
    } catch (err) {
      const errorMessage = err instanceof Error ? err.message : "Unknown error";
      // On error, log and return the error message.
      if (err! instanceof Error) console.log(err);
      console.log(`❌ Error message: ${errorMessage}`);
      res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${errorMessage}`);
      return;
    }

    // Successfully constructed event.
    console.log("✅ Success:", event.id);

    // Cast event data to Stripe object.
    if (
      event.type === "payment_intent.succeeded" ||
      event.type === "checkout.session.completed"
    ) {
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
      console.log(` PaymentIntent: ${JSON.stringify(paymentIntent)}`);

      // @ts-ignore
      const userEmail = paymentIntent.customer_details.email;
      let creditAmount = 0;

      // @ts-ignore
      switch (paymentIntent.amount_subtotal) {
        case 500:
        case 1000:
          creditAmount = 20;
          break;
        case 1900:
        case 3000:
          creditAmount = 100;
          break;
        case 3500:
        case 5000:
          creditAmount = 250;
          break;
        case 7000:
        case 10000:
          creditAmount = 750;
          break;
      }
      await prisma.user.update({
        where: {
          email: userEmail,
        },
        data: {
          credits: {
            increment: creditAmount,
          },
        },
      });

      await prisma.purchase.create({
        data: {
          creditAmount: creditAmount,
          user: {
            connect: {
              email: userEmail,
            },
          },
        },
      });
    } else if (event.type === "payment_intent.payment_failed") {
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
      console.log(
        `❌ Payment failed: ${paymentIntent.last_payment_error?.message}`
      );
    } else if (event.type === "charge.succeeded") {
      const charge = event.data.object as Stripe.Charge;
      console.log(` Charge id: ${charge.id}`);
    } else {
      console.warn(`‍♀️ Unhandled event type: ${event.type}`);
    }

    // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event. Upgraded.
    res.json({ received: true });
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
};

export default cors(webhookHandler as any);

##prisma schema##
datasource db {
  provider          = "postgresql"
  url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
  directUrl         = env("DIRECT_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
}


generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId            String
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.Text
  access_token      String? @db.Text
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.Text
  session_state     String?
  user              User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String     @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?    @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  credits       Int        @default(1)
  location      String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  rooms         Room[]
  purchases     Purchase[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}

model Room {
  id          String   @id @default(cuid())
  replicateId String
  userId      String
  user        User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  inputImage  String
  outputImage String
  prompt      String
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt

  @@unique([replicateId, userId])
}

model Purchase {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  userId       String
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  creditAmount Int
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

Comment: To give some more info:  somebody gave me the comment that my endpoint should be public and not protected like in his opinion it's now. Anybody an idea what to do with this?

Comment: You are getting this error from a Stripe API or your own server endpoint ?

Comment: My problem evolved a bit after I added these event types "payment_intent.succeeded" 
"checkout.session.completed" 
 "payment_intent.payment_failed”. 
"charge.succeeded", now I m getting this back from stripe    " HTTP status code 400 (Bad Request)  "                                                                                  "Webhook Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?"

Answer (score 0):

In general, the main reasons behind getting “No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload” error are:

- Using a wrong webhook secret. I invite you to double check that you are using the correct webhook secret[1].
- The request rawbody is being changed[2]. Make sure that nothing is changing the request body of the webhook event body (e.g. compressor, json middlewares) in your integration.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#roll-endpoint-secrets

[2] [https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#:~:text=Stripe%20requires%20the%20raw%20body%20of%20the%20request%20to%20perform%20signature%20verification.%20If%20you%E2%80%99re%20using%20a%20framework%2C%20make%20sure%20it%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20manipulate%20the%20raw%20body.%20Any%20manipulation%20to%20the%20raw%20body%20of%20the%20request%20causes%20the%20verification%20to%20fail](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#:%7E:text=Stripe%20requires%20the%20raw%20body%20of%20the%20request%20to%20perform%20signature%20verification.%20If%20you%E2%80%99re%20using%20a%20framework%2C%20make%20sure%20it%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20manipulate%20the%20raw%20body.%20Any%20manipulation%20to%20the%20raw%20body%20of%20the%20request%20causes%20the%20verification%20to%20fail).